# Cannot resolve method 'createDirectStream' Java Spark Kafka

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

The following is the Java spark kafka stream code I'm using:

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    SparkConf conf = new SparkConf()
            .setAppName("kafka-sandbox")
            .setMaster("local[*]");
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, new Duration(2000));
    Set<String> topics = Collections.singleton("mytopic");
    Map<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
    kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092");
    JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,
            String.class, String.class, StringDecoder.class, StringDecoder.class, kafkaParams, topics);
    directKafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
        System.out.println("--- New RDD with " + rdd.partitions().size()
                + " partitions and " + rdd.count() + " records");
        rdd.foreach(record -> System.out.println(record._2));
    });
    ssc.start();
    ssc.awaitTermination();
}
```

For some reason it doesn't like some of the createDirectStream parameters even-though this is how its used everywhere. It keeps underlining all the createDirectStream parameters in red, and stating the following in the error log:

```
Cannot resolve method 'createDirectStream(org.apache.spark.streaming.api.java.JavaStreamingContext, java.lang.Class<java.lang.String>, java.lang.Class<java.lang.String>, java.lang.Class<kafka.serializer.StringDecoder>, java.lang.Class<kafka.serializer.StringDecoder>, java.util.Map<java.lang.String,java.lang.Object>, java.util.Set<java.lang.String>)'
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: have you included corresponding jar into uberjar or specified as parameter when starting app? What is the spark version? Do you really need to use obsolete API instead of using structured streaming?

Comment: Note: Streaming library is deprecated... Perhaps you should try Structured Streaming?